# fail2ban detect bad website crawlers

Tags: apache, apache2, fail2ban

Recently my server got attacked from a bad website crawler who searched for ~70.000 folders on my website in ~2 minutes. This caused some server-lags and it might also be a problem if it find some exploits in phpmyadmin or something else.

Now my question: Is there a fail2ban config which can block such scans?

I already found a older one [(link)](http://fips.at/how-to-get-rid-of-http-bots-with-fail2ban.html), but it doesn't match the log strings in my log.

The strings in my log look like:

```
domain.tld:80 <Attacker IP (v4 & v6)> - - [17/Apr/2017:20:45:28 +0200] "GET /ph4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4123 "http://www.google.com" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Answer (score 2):

My regex is not perfect. But it can help:

```
failregex = ^<HOST>.* \".*\" (400|401|403|404|405|413|414|429).*
```

This regex will match for the return code 400,401,403,404,405,413,414,429
You can find the meaning of these codes on this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors)

I hope it can help.